# tethered jailbreak, I don't know what to do?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

I just jailbroke my ipod, and at the end of the process I got a note that said something like "this is a tethered jailbreak, so to reboot you most hit extras and just boot." or something, but i really didn't understand what the heck it meant at all, and my iphone is working just like it was before, it doesn't look any different, but i know i installed it because i did the whole hold power button, hold home button thing and I saw the load in screen and stuff.

I thought maybe I wouldn't be able to reboot my phone without having a cord, but i just did and it was fine , i dont know why my phone looks the same what happened whats wrong anyone help?????

ps, i have iphone 4 and am running ios 6

Comment: A tethered jailbreak means to actively access the items featured in a jailbroken phone, you will need to reboot using the software used to jailbreak the phone. As always, if looking to jailbreak a phone, it's best to wait for an untethered version of the jailbreak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Per [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_jailbreaking)
>
> An **untethered** jailbreak has the property that if the user turns the device off and back on, the device will start up completely, and the kernel will be patched without the help of a computer – in other words, it will be jailbroken after each reboot.[36]
>
> *[crappy]* With a **tethered** jailbreak, if the device starts back up on its own, it will no longer have a patched kernel, and it may get stuck in a partially started state; in order for it to start completely and with a patched kernel, it essentially must be "re-jailbroken" with a computer (using the "boot tethered" feature of a jailbreaking tool) each time it is turned on.[37]
>
> *[you]* A device with a tethered jailbreak may be able to have a semi-tethered solution, which means that when the device starts up on its own, it will no longer have a patched kernel (so it will not be able to run modified code), but it will still be usable for normal functions.[38] With a semi-tethered solution, the user can also choose to start the device with the help of the jailbreaking tool in order for it to start with a patched kernel (jailbroken).

As @kobaltz mentioned, it is generally best to wait for an Untethered solution unless you have some major reason to require a jailbreak immediately.  By jailbreaking, you also should wait on any updates of the system software since Apple actively works to inhibit jailbreaking (and an update will remove it 99.9% of the time).

**What you should do** --> Boot attached to your computer, there should be an option to boot tethered. (that is assuming you care for running jailbreak tweaks).